# Animation distorting

Tags: animation, rigify

My animation goes all distorted when I have it follow any path.
Any ideas of what I may have done wrong, or missed?
It works just fine if not following a path.

Do I need to 'Bake' it? (can someone explain why it's called baking?)
--When I'm on the animation tab, when I go to Object>>Rigid Body>>Bake to keyframes, bake to keyframes is greyed out.

I followed an animation/rigging tutorial on youtube, but the guy was exporting to Unity and stopped after keyframing the animation, so I think I'm missing some additional steps.

If it helps any, this is a 3d model I imported from Meshroom.
V 2.81.16, windows 10 64bit

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: The armature should follow the path, not the bear. There are other issues in the rig itself, but the deformation in the picture above is due to that.

Comment: Okay, that fixed THAT problem. Thanks :) Now the armature follows the path, but the bear stays at the world origin and deforms as armature walks away. (edit. Figured this out. I forgot to parent the object and set automatic weights. It works now...Nice see how things work and whatnot. Learn by failure :)

 What issues are there in my rig?

Comment: Several as I see it now. bear is parented to the curve, several modifiers for the bear, objects origin not aligned to the model, armature and model not aligned in rest pose, bone placements relatively to the model (hips in particular).